# Show table data upon attaching MDF file to SQL Server Mgmt Studio

Tags: sql-server

I have MDF file , I attached it to SQL Server Mgmt Studio and I find the database's tables and columns but no data at all !

How can I retrieve the data from each table and browsing through rows and columns ?

Comment: did you right click on a table and click `Select Top 1000 rows`?

Comment: I used `select` command & It works , this is my first time with SSMS and I don't know if it has a browser for the data and enable editing or should I use commands only !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ### Browse Top 1000
>
> As suggested by @paqogomez right click on the table name "tblXYZ" and select "select top 
>   1000 rows. This opens a query editor and displays the query code at top and the result 
>   set at the bottom of the screen.

```
SELECT TOP 1000
        col1,
        col2,
        col3
FROM tblXYZ
```

### Simple select statement

> You could modify the above query code to remove "TOP 1000" to get all rows from the 
>   table.

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3
FROM tblXYZ
```

> Repeat the same for right click "Edit Top 200" rows for editing.